# RxJava Having trouble Converting one list to another list

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to convert `Flowable<List<TaskEntity>>` to `Flowable<List<Task>>` but something is wrong. 
To understand the problem I tried with converting a simpler list and it is working fine. When I try to apply the same logic to my actual problem, it is not working.

---

This logic is giving me expected output. **[No.1 No.2 No.3]**

```
Flowable.fromArray(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
        .flatMapIterable(ids->ids)
        .map(s->"No. "+s)
        .toList()
        .toFlowable()
        .subscribe(
                t -> Log.d(TAG, "getAllActiveTasks: "+t)
        );
```

This logic is not working . **It prints Nothing**

```
    mTaskDao.getAllTasks(STATE_ACTIVE)
            .flatMapIterable(task -> task)
            .map(Task::create)
            .toList()
            .toFlowable()

            .subscribe(
                    t -> Log.d(TAG, "getAllActiveTasks: "+t)
            );
```

---

**Edit 1**
This is how Task.create() looks like.

```
     public static Task create(TaskEntity eTask) {
         Task task = new Task(eTask.getTaskId(), eTask.getTaskTitle(), eTask.getTaskStatus());
         task.mTaskDescription = eTask.getTaskDescription();
         task.mCreatedAt = eTask.getCreatedAt();
         task.mTaskDeadline = eTask.getTaskDeadline();
         return task;
     }
```

---

**Solution**

As mentioned in the comments, toList() can only work if emitting source has finite number of items to emit. Since Flowable from Dao method contains an infinite stream of objects, toList() was not being used correctly by me.

*Checkout this comment for the exact way to solve this problem.* 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50318832/4989435

Comment: how does TaskEntry and Task correlate to each other?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque, they are pretty much same. TaskEntity conforms to my DB table and Task makes more sense from presentation point of view. So in the  Task.create() i will change things like converting timestamps in TaskEntity to Java Date objects.

Comment: `toList` requires a finite source but `getAllTasks` is likely infinite, which is unfortunately quite typical from DAOs backed by Android databases. Change the `getAllTasks` to `Single`, use `take(1)`, use `timeout()`, or use `flatMap(Observable.fromIterable().map().toList())` instead of `flatMapIterable`.

Comment: @akarnokd, your explanation does make sense to me but I am still confused. I want to receive any updates made to tasks in db. And I think using Single would mean it stops after running once. Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toList` requires a finite source but `getAllTasks` is likely infinite, which is unfortunately quite typical from DAOs backed by Android databases. Change the `getAllTasks` to `Single`, use `take(1)`, use `timeout()`, or use `flatMap(Observable.fromIterable().map().toList())` instead of `flatMapIterable`.

> I want to receive any updates made to tasks in db.

In this case, you need the latter option:

```java
mTaskDao.getAllTasks(STATE_ACTIVE)
        .flatMapSingle(task -> 
             Observable.fromIterable(task)
            .map(Task::create)
            .toList()
        )
        .subscribe(
                t -> Log.d(TAG, "getAllActiveTasks: "+t)
        );
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. You have saved me so much trouble. I have just picked up RxJava again (after a brief introduction to it last year). I need to invest more time to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use only map operator to convert TaskEntity to Task. I have created [sample](http://demohttps://github.com/gokhanaliccii/RxAndroidKata/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/gokhanaliccii/rxjavawithdagger/ConvertEntityToModelTest.java). You can check my solution which uses only map operator

Comment: thanks for the sample. I went through it but it doesn't address my problem. I want the final result from chaining to be <Flowable<List<Task>>, your sample was returning <Flowable<Task>>. The main culprit I believe is the .toList() method which is not working correctly. Can you try to update your sample to emit List of tasks instead of emitting individual tasks?

Comment: Please add the code to your answer so the information won't be lost for future generations.